# Error: Cause: com/google/common/collect/Iterators after pasting in xml layout code

Tags: android, xml

I pasted in some XML layout code from one file to another to try a new layout and after that my project wouldn't compile. I got the message

> "Error: cause: com/google/common/collect/Iterators".

I changed the code back but I still got the same message. I checked all the XML value files and there is nothing missing. I then tried to make a new project and got the same message. I hope someone can help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can read up on how to [ask] a question and create a [mcve]. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by changing my project directory to a directory with no spaces in the path.